# How to prevent multiple renders in Vue v-for lists

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've captured the current code I have here:
https://jsfiddle.net/prsauer/Lnhu2avp/71

The basic issue is that for each click on a list item every item's computeStyle is called -- I'd prefer for each click to only produce a single recompute of the style

```
<div id="editor">
  <div v-for="item in dungeons" :key="item.isOpened">
    <div v-on:click="clickedChest(item)" v-bind:style="computeChestStyle(item)">
      {{ item.name }} {{ item.isOpened }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

var dgnData = [
    { name: "Lobby", isOpened: false },
  { name: "Side", isOpened: false },
];

new Vue({
  el: '#editor',
  data: { dungeons: dgnData },
  computed: { },
  methods: {
    clickedChest: chest => {
      chest.isOpened = !chest.isOpened;
      console.log("##### Clicked chest", chest);
    },
    computeChestStyle:
        item => {
        console.log("computeStyle", item);
        return item.isOpened ? "color: red" : "color: blue";
        }
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you clarify *why* you want to avoid the observed behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Function calls get re-evaluated on every update of the view. If you want results to be cached to only re-render as needed, you need a computed. That means you need to create a component for your `item`, and create the computed in the component.

Comment: I had a feeling that somehow component-izing the children was going to be the answer. I'll give it a shot soon to see how it plays out, thanks for the tip